# Apache Camel cxfEndpoint

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to use WSRR (Websphere Service Registry and Repository) to retrieve the endpoint of the service that I'm consuming. I have a method which will lookup and return the endpoint of the service. I've set this to the `publishedEndpointUrl` in the properties.

But, it does not replace the value of the "address" and if I remove "address", it throws me an error. Is there another way to achieve this?

This is what I tried:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="test" address="https://..." serviceClass="...">
   <cxf:properties>
     <entry key="publishedEndpointUrl value="#{wsrr.getEndpoint()}">
   </cxf:cxfEndpoint>
<cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving?

Comment: If I remove "address" value, it says "Invalid address. Endpoint address cannot be null". But I can't provide a static url in the address. It should be dynamic which is why I was trying to use publishedEndpointUrl with a method call.